# How can I control ads frequency?

Tags: unity, unity-ads

This question was already asked a while ago, and I wanted to check the present situation:

- Can I control ads frequency from the **dashboard**? (e.g. frequency
  capping in Admob)
- Can I control ads frequency through **Unity IAP API**?
- If not, does that mean that I need to implement all that **"frequency
  control"** functionality manually?

Answer (score 0):

yes.
admob and unity and other qd services have builtin ad frequency control for any user but they only return no add error when there is no ad. but you have to control them in client side or maybe you can have mid server that manages connection of your clients with adverisement server if you are afraid oc heating or ad overuse